# ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a dataframe with the following schema:

```
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- keyNote: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

This is the best I managed to do:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id",LongType(), True),
    StructField("keyNote",StructType([
            StructField("key",StringType(),True),
            StructField("note",StringType(),True)
        ])),
    StructField("details",MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True))
    ])

df = spark\
    .createDataFrame([("idd",("keyy","notee"),("keyy","valuee")),schema])
```

But I'm getting an exception:

> ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `schema` is correct, but the test data is wrong. Please check below example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id",LongType(), True),
    StructField("keyNote",StructType([
            StructField("key",StringType(),True),
            StructField("note",StringType(),True)
        ])),
    StructField("details",MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True))
    ])


test_data = [[9, {"key": "mykey", "note": "mynote"}, {"a": "val_a", "b": "val_b"}]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_data,schema=schema) 
df.show(20, False)
df.printSchema()
```

output of above code:

```
+---+---------------+------------------------+
|id |keyNote        |details                 |
+---+---------------+------------------------+
|9  |[mykey, mynote]|[a -> val_a, b -> val_b]|
+---+---------------+------------------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- keyNote: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
 |-- details: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error there:

```py
>>> spark.createDataFrame([("idd",("keyy","notee"),("keyy","valuee"))])
DataFrame[_1: string, _2: struct<_1:string,_2:string>, _3: struct<_1:string,_2:string>]
```

you are not closing a bracket `]` properly.

Besides, you cannot give "idd" - a string - if you declare a LondType, and you must not forget about other elements:

```py
>>> spark.createDataFrame([(123123,[("keyy","notee"),("keyy","valuee")], {})], schema)
DataFrame[id: bigint, keyNote: struct<key:string,note:string>, details: map<string,string>]
```